# Pass custom headers using request module

Tags: node.js, express

I am using npm request module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to post binary content to a servlet. The binary content is received as part of http request, using the npm request module it is then posted to the J2ee server.

Along with the post, I need to pass some custom headers. I am using the below code to do that

```
var req = require('request');
function upload(request, response) {
    var options = {
      headers: {
        'customheader1': 'val1',
        'customheader2': 'val2'
      }
    };

    var target = req.post('http://'+host+':'+port+'/myapp/Upload', options);
    request.pipe(target);

    target.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('Uploaded with headers');
    })
}
```

However, the headers are going as blank to the server. What would be the right way to pass headers using request.post?

Comment: Should work. Are you sending the exact values like in your question, or something specific?

Answer (score 2):

As per request Docs (http://github.com/request/request)

```
var req = require('request');
function upload(request, response) {
  var options = {
    url: 'http://'+host+':'+port+'/myapp/Upload',
    headers: {
      'customheader1': 'val1',
      'customheader2': 'val2'
      }
    };

  var target = req.post( options, function(err,data){
         console.log('uploaded with headers')
  })
  request.pipe(target);
}
```

Comment: Where's the URL? Also, if you pass a callback you probably won't get a stream back.

Comment: Sorry. the inexistant url was a typo. Corrected no

Comment: About the callback , as per documentation, it's the only way to get some kind of results WHEN req.post ends.

Comment: No, it's not, this [this](https://github.com/request/request#streaming) (example uses `request.get()`, but the same applies to `request.post()`).